# How to pass data using checkbox if single item is selected on shopping cart in asp.netcore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

How to pass data using checkbox if single item  or multiple item is selected on shopping cart for ecomm book website using asp.netcore
like amazon in shopping cart one item selected

I have only placed check boxes on design but couldn't know how will I pass data

Answer (score 0):

Data can be transferred by setting the name attribute of the HTML form element. The keys of these data will be passed to the server together with the corresponding values when the form is submitted. Then in your controller, you can create an action method to receive these parameters. Here is an asp.net core MVC example you can use as a reference：

My model:

```
public class Book
{
     public List<string> Info { get; set; } = new List<string>();
     public string[] Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Page:

```
@model Book

<form asp-action="UpdateCart" method="post">
    <table>
     
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Info.Count; i++)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.Info[i]" name="Selected" checked />
                <strong>@Model.Info[i]</strong>
                <br />
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Update </button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{

     Book book = new Book();    
     book.Info.Add("Jane");
     book.Info.Add("Harry");
     book.Info.Add("Time");

     return View(book);
}
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UpdateCart(Book book )
    {
           

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

When I click button:

[image]

The data will be accepted:

[image]

If this example does not solve your problem, can  you share your relevant project code? So that we can better help you.